# Using non-supported hardware in a ROS system

Tags: ros, c++, hardware, ubuntu, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to integrate a small radiation detector into a robot's sensory system, and am very new to both ROS (indigo) and Linux (Ubuntu 14.04).

The detector came with files and folders (containing various CMakeLists, .cpp, and .h files) I used to build the device driver for it so that it could work on a Linux system. It has a driver module (.ko file) and its own library (.so file); all I did to compile the library was use "cmake" while in its main folder, "make install" to install the driver module while in the driver module file, and then added a rule in /etc/udev/rules.d to disconnect it from the standard USB driver and connect it to the driver I installed.

I would like to be able to use the data coming from the detector in a ROS system, which I think means that it just needs to be able to publish on a ROS topic. The question I have is: what would be the easiest/smartest way to go about making this happen?

I have heard I could write a ROS wrapper for the device and include it as a node in some sensory package, and I have heard I can just write a script that includes roscpp and run a loop to publish incoming data. If this is too general a question, or if more information is needed to provide an answer, let me know and I'll gladly try to accommodate. Any help would be much appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267252/using-non-supported-hardware-in-a-ros-system/) by [JackBall](https://answers.ros.org/users/31325/jackball/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-07-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I have heard I could write a ROS wrapper for the device and include it as a node in some sensory package, and I have heard I can just write a script that includes roscpp and run a loop to publish incoming data.

You heard correct! That's going to be the general idea here. You'll likely have to define a custom message type for your sensor (see tutorials [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv#Creating_a_msg) and [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/DefiningCustomMessages)), but, essentially, you will just read the data from the sensor, fill in your custom message, then publish the message with a ROS publisher.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2017-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JackBall](https://answers.ros.org/users/31325/jackball/) on 2017-07-25**:
Thanks for the response, this makes the path much clearer to me. In order to read data from the detector, I have to use a command from the custom library for the detector driver; if I'm doing this all in a catkin package, will the package be able to recognize this detector-specific command?